# Raspberry pi resetting after reboot

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to over clock my rasbian raspberry pi, but when I change any files beyond /sys/devices/system/cpu and restart, the changes are not saved. I tried echoing to the files and nano and cat. Nothing will work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, belongs on Raspberry Pi forum

Comment: @benPearce Ok sorry for the inconvenience:)

Comment: I'd suggest overclocking the pi using the conventional way, type sudo raspi-config into your terminal and navigate to the overclocking section

Answer (score 0):

SysFS (mounted on /sys) is not a regular filesystem, the elements in this FS represent different aspects and options exposed by the kernel and modules, as such, those parameters are not persisted on secondary memory.

Is normal that changes under that directory are not saved (the only ones I recall to be saved are some settings about power saving in some notebooks, those settings were saved in the BIOS), in order to have the changes on every reboot you should create a init script or modify /etc/rc.local (on Debian based systems as Raspbian).

Answer (score 0):

My SDcard was doing the same thing.

I tried to re-burn the image to the card, but it still had the same problem.

I burnt the image to another SD card, and it worked right away.

More than likely the card was corrupted or damaged